# Compile error using map iterators

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, compiler-errors

In my header file I have included the std::map and use the appropriate namespace.
One of my members is:

```
map<unsigned int, double> pT_Spam;
```

And in my .cpp file I attempt to do something that I have been doing frequently for some time now:

```
for(map<unsigned int, double>::iterator it=pT_Spam.begin() ; it!=pT_Spam.end() ; it++) {/*code*/}
```

The above is even mentioned in one the examples of using std::map at cplusplus.com . Even though I have done pretty much the same in other parts of the code which cause no compile errors, on this particular line I get the following error from Cygwin:

```
error: conversion from `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, double> >' to non-scalar type `std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, double> >' requested
```

Which seems rather strange. Any idea what might be wrong? (my header is, of course, included in my .cpp)

Comment: It's complaining that the iterator returned by begin() is a const_iterator, but you're assigning it to an iterator.  But I'm not sure why, this looks right to me too.  What compiler is this?

Comment: [begin()](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/begin/) seems to be capable of returning non-const iterators as well.
I use Cygwin's g++ on windows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It would seem that at the scope this loop exists, the map is const. For example, is the loop in a class method declared const, like so?

```
void method() const // const method
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

or passed as a const argument, like this?

```
void function(const map<unsigned int, double>& pT_Spam)
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

If it is, you must use const iterators:

```
for(map<unsigned int, double>::const_iterator it=pT_Spam.begin() ; it!=pT_Spam.end() ; it++)
{
    /*code*/
}
```

Or, if you're using C++11, then you should use the auto keyword:

```
for(auto it=pT_Spam.begin() ; it!=pT_Spam.end(); it++)
{
    /*code*/
}
```

Since in the case you've shown you must use const iterators, you can't use them to modify the map or the data within it. That's const correctness, and it's a good thing :).

Comment: -.25 for using auto in a way that kills kittens. ;)

Comment: An alternative is to mark the member as [`mutable`](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/rants/mutable.html). But don't tell anyone I told you that :-)

Comment: The method running the loop is indeed const, and that makes me understand why the map is const in it's scope as well. Considering I don't need to edit it in this method, const iterators seem to the answer.

Comment: @Chet Simpson Herb Sutter says my kittens are safe :).

Comment: What would be the problem with the auto in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the error says you're trying to cast a const_iterator to an iterator. You say that `pT_Spam` is a member. Is it a member of a const object? If it is, begin() and end() will return const_iterators.

Comment: Not sure to be honest, it's a declared private member of my 'nbclassifier' class, while the method that performs the loop is a member of that class as well.

Comment: An alternative is to mark the member as [`mutable`](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/rants/mutable.html). But don't tell anyone I told you that :-)

Comment: Const is coming in somewhere.  If the member variable isn't declared const, and if the method isn't declared const, then maybe the method is being called on a const object (which would make the member variable implicitly const).  Does the compiler error come with a call stack?  EDIT: wait, it would have to be a const method if it's being called on a const object.

Comment: Where in the error does it say that?  it says : conversion from GARBAGE to non-scalar type LINE_NOISE requested.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use const_iterators for maps, so it should be:

```
for(map<unsigned int, double>::const_iterator it = \\and so on
```

Edit: As pointed out the above is right, but for completely **wrong** reasons (maps have non-const iterators. What was I thinking exactly? I don't know). Most likely your map is defined as const (as pointed out in another answer).

Comment: Won't that cause issues when altering their value(it++)? Also, I have been using regular iterators for similar loops so far and never had problems.

Comment: Um, what? map has non-const iterators.

Comment: @JohnAthanasiou: A mutable const-iterator is not the same as a const non-const iterator! Think `T const *` vs `T * const`.

Comment: John: const_iterators aren't themselves const, they just refer to a const object.

Answer (score 1):

for(map::iterator it=pT_Spam.begin() ; it!=pT_Spam.end() ; it++)

chage it to

for(map::const_iterator it=pT_Spam.begin() ; it!=pT_Spam.end() ; it++)

As it is pointing to constant value, so the iterator must be also of const type.